# Autorización vía token me devuelve "Authentication credentials were not provided."(Django)

Tags: python

Estoy usando Httpie para probar mis API-REST:

```
http GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/bussines/ "Authorization : Token 28b8fab8aa6cceac3f58cc0022ff0312c317c8f4"
```

A la hora de enviar el token para la autorización siempre me sale el siguiente error (estoy utilizando zsh no bash):

```
(venv4)% http GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/bussines/ "Authorization : Token 28b8fab8aa6cceac3f58cc0022ff0312c317c8f4"
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 58
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 17 Nov 2020 10:10:18 GMT
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.6
Vary: Accept
WWW-Authenticate: Token
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY

{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

He intentado enviar el token de varias formas :

```
"Authorization : Token 28b8fab8aa6cceac3f58cc0022ff0312c317c8f4"
'Authorization : Token 28b8fab8aa6cceac3f58cc0022ff0312c317c8f4'
Authorization = Token 28b8fab8aa6cceac3f58cc0022ff0312c317c8f4
Authorization:Token 28b8fab8aa6cceac3f58cc0022ff0312c317c8f4
```

Y muchas mas , pero ninguna da resultado.

Comment: Me parece que te sobra un espacio entre _Authorization_ y los dos puntos. En Django al menos es sin ellos: `Authorization: Token 28b8fab8aa6cceac3f58cc0022ff0312c317c8f4`

Comment: Ejecuta el comando `http` con la opción `-v` para que, además de las cabeceras en la respuesta, muestre las cabeceras en la petición. Edita la pregunta para poner también esas cabeceras a ver si se ve algo raro.

Comment: Al usar tu opcion fedorqui'SO deja de dañar' me aparece un error 500

Comment: sería bueno que indicaras cómo tienes configurado el Django e incluso el Apache. ¿Puedes mostrar los errores del log? Suelen estar en `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: talvez debas enviar el token como "HTTP_Authorization : Token etc", no recuerdo si el "HTTP" va en mayusculas o no, trata de imprimir por consola el request de las cabeceras que te llega a tu api de django, asi verás como te está llegando el token.